# OAuth Cognito ID token unauthorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool/app client setup with OAuth flow and standard scopes (email, admin, etc.) and several 3rd party providers (google, azure, etc.). I would like to get the identity data in the request context which mean I would need to use the id token but using the id token gets me an unauthorized response from api gateway while the access token works as expected. I remember reading somewhere that custom scopes doesn't allow for id token auth but I don't have custom scopes setup. Any insight into what's going on here?

Comment: Are you using AWS REST API Gateway or HTTP API Gateway? For REST API Gateway, access tokens only work if you have specified one or more OAuth scope for your endpoint. On the other hand, id tokens only work if no OAuth scopes are specified.

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar REST, that makes sense. Is HTTP the newer version? Also how can I get Identity info in the request context if I have to use scopes? I want to put my endpoint lambda into a VPC but want to avoid doing all the setup necessary to get access call out to cognito from behind the vpc

Comment: HTTP was released later but I won't describe it as a 'newer' version, they are meant for different usecases. [Here is a detailed comparison](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) between the two. Scopes are only present in access tokens, not id tokens. You will have to access the APIs using access tokens and then get the user details using the [USERINFO endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html).

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar please post this as an answer when you have the time so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Integrate a REST API with an Amazon Cognito user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html):

> With the COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorizer, if the OAuth Scopes option
> isn't specified, API Gateway treats the supplied token as an identity
> token and verifies the claimed identity against the one from the user
> pool. Otherwise, API Gateway treats the supplied token as an access
> token and verifies the access scopes that are claimed in the token
> against the authorization scopes declared on the method.

OAuth Scopes are only present in access tokens. Based on the fact that access tokens work, you have specified one or more OAuth scopes for your endpoint.

If you have a valid access token, you can use its value to get information about the authenticated user using the [USERINFO endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html).